# php mail: headers not reading html

Tags: php, html, email

I have two problems.

1) Upon of receival of the email, it does not capture the html within the body

2) It only issues the email to the recepient info@info.com and not info2@info.com

Everything else works fine.

```
$to = 'info@info.com, info2@info.com';
        $subject = "New interested recruiter: " .$cleanEmail. "";
        $header = "From: info@info.com";
        $header .= "Reply-To: info@info.com";
        $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
                $message = "<html>";
                $message .= "<body>";
        $message = "New interested recruiter: ".$cleanEmail."<br><br>";
                $message .= $cleanMessage;
                $message .= "</body>";
                $message .= "</html>";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $header) or die ("Failure");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: *KerPlunk...* `$message = "New interested recruiter: ".$cleanEmail."<br><br>";`

Comment: RTM too http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php it's all in there.

Comment: I'm not sure you can define 2 values in $to. Instead try using the To header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here.

[The manual for the `mail()` function states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

```
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';
```

therefore, do as the manual states.

as well as using a MIME: (also from the manual)...

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Then the missing concatenate is breaking your message variable

```
$message  = "New interested recruiter: ".$cleanEmail."<br><br>";
         ^ missing dot
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add header like this ..

```
$header = "From: info@info.com\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: info@info.com\r\n";
$header  .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
```